# How to display a dictionary keys in editorwindow in a EditorGUILayout.ObjectField in a row?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public class ScriptFinder : EditorWindow
{
    static ScriptFinder window;
    static Dictionary<string, string> dictio = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    [MenuItem("EditorUtility/Script Finder")]
    static void OpenScriptFinder()
    {
        window = (ScriptFinder)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(ScriptFinder));

        MonoBehaviour[] scripts = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();
        foreach (MonoBehaviour script in scripts)
        {
            Type scriptType = script.GetType();
            var scope = scriptType.Namespace;
            if (scope == null || !scope.StartsWith("Unity"))
            {
                if (!dictio.Keys.Contains(script.gameObject.name))
                {
                    dictio.Add(script.gameObject.name, scriptType.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.white;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dictio)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(pair.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

the ObjectField should get SerializedProperty and pair.key is a string.

in the end I want to display each key and it's value near it.
the key is a string of a gameobject name and the value is a name of a script attached to the gameobject.

but I want to display the key's as gameobjects in the ObjectField.

Answer (score 0):

working code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using static Unity.VisualScripting.Member;

public class ScriptFinder : EditorWindow
{
    static ScriptFinder window;
    static Dictionary<GameObject, string> dictio = new Dictionary<GameObject, string>();

    [MenuItem("EditorUtility/Script Finder")]
    static void OpenScriptFinder()
    {
        window = (ScriptFinder)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(ScriptFinder));

        MonoBehaviour[] scripts = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();
        foreach (MonoBehaviour script in scripts)
        {
            Type scriptType = script.GetType();
            var scope = scriptType.Namespace;
            if (scope == null || !scope.StartsWith("Unity"))
            {
                if (!dictio.Keys.Contains(script.gameObject))
                {
                    dictio.Add(script.gameObject, scriptType.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.white;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<GameObject, string> pair in dictio)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(pair.Key, typeof(GameObject), true);
            EditorGUILayout.TextField(pair.Value);

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }
}
```